# Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined - express js session

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am learning nodejs express and I am getting below error is when I am trying to destroy session for logout functionality

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined
at router.get (/var/www/html/nodepug/routes/users.js:169:14)
```

Below is code for destroying session my users.js route file

```
router.get('/logout',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.session);
    req.session.destroy(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });    
});
```

Help me to solve this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `delete req.session;` rather than  `req.session.destroy();`. It  works fine for me.

Comment: sorry not working delete req.session; because i console.log(req.session) it is showing my session

Comment: Session is not working at all.. i am saving session as session.users_id=result[0].users_id;

Comment: I solved it with delete session.users_id Thanks buddy @Sariful

Comment: You can check if req.session already exists or not (e.g: `if (req.session) { ... }`) then execute `delete req.session` this will destroy entire session not only the `session.users_id`

Comment: I tried but it's not destroying session, as i told you in 2nd comment that i am saving my session in this way session.users_id=result[0].users_id;

Comment: Hmm, you have to delete all session keys manually as it is not deleting entirely.

Comment: Because when i am trying to save session with req.session.users_id is throwing error that users_id is undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174488/discussion-between-usersn-and-sariful).